# Javascript - Using timeago function with Algolia autocomplete

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use timeAgo function from these [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3J9Dz/184/). I put it in a file and I am calling it in my view like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/material.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/slider.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/timeago.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Include AlgoliaSearch JS Client and autocomplete.js library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/autocomplete.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Control Center for Material Kit: activating the ripples, parallax effects, scripts from the example pages etc -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/material-kit.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Part of the script where the Algolia autocomplete template is looks like this:

```
{
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(videos, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'title',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Videos</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>'
                + '<a href="/player/' + suggestion.id + '">'
                +   '<div class="media">'
                +     '<div class="media-left">'
                +       '<img class="media-object" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myUrl/' + suggestion.video_id + '_1.jpg">'
                +     '</div>'
                +     '<div class="media-body">'
                +       '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + '<small><abbr class="timeago" title="' + suggestion.created_at + '">' + suggestion.created_at + '</abbr></small>' + '</p>'
                +       '<small> ' + '</small>'
                +     '</div>'
                +   '</div>'
                + '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
```

But the timestamp is still visible and not time ago. No errors are shown in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete adds html code a long time after DOM is ready, so `timeago.js` code is executed when there is still no any autocomplete code.

You have to call `timeAgo` function again **right after rendering** of new code using `autocomplete:updated` event, not waiting for 60 or 10 seconds.

```
//attach custom event handler - autocomplete:updated triggers when dataset is rendered
autocomplete('#search-input', { hint: false }, [
    {
      source: ...,
      displayKey: ...,
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  ]).on('autocomplete:updated', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
    timeAgo('.timeago');
  });
```

This solution can lead to many instanses of `timeAgo` javascript timeouts. Fix it with global `timeAgoTimeout = setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);` and `clearTimeout(timeAgoTimeout)` before timeAgo.

Example that works with dynamic elements you can find in the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mge45ugr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize timeago again on your

```
<abbr class="timeago">
```

after the autocompletion because it was generated after the page load. Jquery "onload" function doesn't work on ajax-generated html code.

Answer (score 0):

In your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3J9Dz/184/), notice that the function that actuates the DOM changes is on a timer. It runs every 60 seconds, which means that all `timeago` elements are refreshed every 60 seconds.

In your case, you are likely calling the `timeago` only once when the page loads. When Algolia runs, it generates new DOM elements (according to your template) which includes the elements with the `timeago` class. But when those new elements are rendered, the timeago actuation has already completed and isn't running again.

You basically need to tell the timeago function to run again so it can transform those new `timeago` elements. You can either put that function on a timer, like your example, or you can trigger the function after your template has finished rendering in the DOM. I can't tell you how to trigger it after the elements are rendered in your app because I can't see enough of your code. But if you want to put it on a timer, it's something like this:

```
// update time every 10 seconds
setTimeout(timeAgo, 10000);
```

Here is a modified fiddle that I created based on your example.

http://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/hkvjkbd0/2/

It simulates the basic idea of what you are trying to do. The timer is set to run every 10 seconds. And 5 seconds after the page loads, I inject some text into the DOM (with `class=timeago`). When the timer kicks in 5 seconds after that, the text is transformed properly.

In your case, you will either need to tweak the timer settings or, a better solution would be to trigger the timeago actuator to execute after your elements have been rendered to the DOM.